# $C\subseteq D$. Prove $\mathcal P (C)$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal P(D)$.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

> Let $C$ and $D$ be sets, with $C\subseteq D$. Prove $\mathcal P(C)$ is a subgroup of $\mathcal P(D)$.

I can't easily see a proof for this, so I tried working on a counterexample. If I could just show that $\mathcal P(C)$ is not a group, then it would not be a subgroup of $\mathcal P(D)$. Basically, I looked for an instance when a power set fails to be a group (by identity or inverse, perhaps).

I suspect that the theorem is actually true, but can't figure out how to prove it. I started with this:
$$\mathcal P(C) \subseteq \mathcal P(D)$$ but don't know where to go from here. I have to prove that this set $\mathcal P(C)$ is actually a group, right? How can I do this? (Looking for hints--please don't give full solutions).

Thanks.

Comment: So $P_X$ is the power set of $X$?  And the operation is symmetric difference?

Comment: Yes, it is the power set. I don't quite understand your second question--the operation is unspecified.

Comment: To have a group you need not only a set of elements, but an operation on those elements.  What is the operation on the power set of a set that makes it a group?  (I would guess symmetric difference, since that works.)

Comment: Assuming symmetric difference is your operation, you just need to notice that the operation on $P_C$ is the same as on $P_D$, and then show that, for $X,Y\in P_C$, one has $X\triangle Y\in P_C$ (since each element is its own inverse).

Comment: For the sake of counterexample, could I just choose an operation that _doesn't_ make $P_C$ a group? Then I could disprove the theorem, right? Because right now $P_C$ is just the power set of the set $C$. There is nothing that says either of them is a group.

Comment: Hmm. Probably not. The way the question is worded suggests that $P_D$ *is* a group, and you are to show that its subset $P_C$ is a subgroup under the operation inherited from $P_D$. (Moreover, since the question asserts that this is true, why are you looking for a counter-example?)

Comment: You're right. I believe that is the case. I will just proceed assuming symmetric difference operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Assuming the group operation on $P_D$ is the symmetric difference, don't bother looking for a counter-example.
2. Note that the identity element of $P_D$ is the empty set $\emptyset$ and each element is its own inverse.
3. Apply the *subgroup criterion*: a subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup if, and only if, it is non-empty and $xy^{-1}\in H$, for all $x,y\in H$.

Comment: Okay, I showed that the identity is $e=\varnothing$ and the inverse is itself (too much work to type). As for part 3 of your list, I struggle to show some of it. Firstly, how do we know $C\not = \varnothing$? If $C=\varnothing$ then $P_C=\varnothing$. Clearly, this would still satisfy $C\subseteq D$. Is this the same kind of trivial "dead end" you just told me to avoid? Also (assuming that $P_C\not = \varnothing$) I showed $xy^{-1}\in P_C \forall x,y\in P_C$ simply because, by definition of a group, if $x,y\in P_C$ ($P_C$ a group) then $xy\in P_C$ hence $xy^{-1}\in P_C$ because $y^{-1}\in P_C$

Comment: Wow, that was long and ugly. Sorry

Comment: If $C=\emptyset$, then $P_C = \{\emptyset\}\neq\emptyset$; i.e., a set with one element. As for the latter part, it sounds like you are assuming what you need to prove (that $P_C$ is indeed a group). You need to show that, if $X,Y\in P_C$ (i.e., if $X,Y\subseteq C$), then $X\triangle Y\in P_C$ (i.e., $X\triangle Y\subseteq C$).

Comment: Ah. I forgot that $\{\varnothing\}\not = \varnothing$. I think I know how to do the latter part. Is it true that if $X,Y\in P_C$ then $X \setminus Y\in P_C$ and $Y \setminus X\in P_C$? It seems to me that this would hold true in power sets. If so, I can easily finish the problem. e

Comment: ...But I have to show it. Not sure how.